# Bluetooth connection Lost on Activity Reload

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

I am trying to connect the bluetooth printer device, connection lost every time my activity gets reloaded. What might be the reason? Activity is reloading when clicked on "next" button.

Here's the code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_sales_return);

    mActivity = Activity_Sales_Return.this;



        if(internet.HaveNetworkConnection()){
        try {
            mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();


                    try {

                        statusBT = false;
                        enableBT();
                        openBT();


                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
        }
        }
  void findBT() {

        try {

            Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter
                    .getBondedDevices();
            if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
                for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {



                     if (device.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(bt_Name.trim()))              
              {
                        mmDevice = device;

                        break;
                    }

                }
            }
           showToast("Bluetooth Device Found");
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    void enableBT(){
        try{

            if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {

            }

            if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                findBT();
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Tries to open a connection to the bluetooth printer device
    void openBT() throws IOException {
        try {
            // Standard SerialPortService ID
            UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-
00805F9B34FB");
            System.out.println("====mmdevice: "+mmDevice);
            mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID
                    .fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
            mmSocket.connect();
            mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
            mmInputStream = mmSocket.getInputStream();

            beginListenForData();

            showToast("Bluetooth Opened");

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            showToast("Unable to connect device, Please try again.");
            e.printStackTrace();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            showToast("Unable to connect device, Please try again.");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

// After opening a connection to bluetooth printer device,
// we have to listen and check if a data were sent to be printed.
void beginListenForData() {
    try {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();

        // This is the ASCII code for a newline character
        final byte delimiter = 10;

        stopWorker = false;
        readBufferPosition = 0;
        readBuffer = new byte[1024];

        workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()
                        && !stopWorker) {

                    try {

                        int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();
                        if (bytesAvailable > 0) {
                            byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                            mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);
                            for (int i = 0; i < bytesAvailable; i++) {
                                byte b = packetBytes[i];
                                if (b == delimiter) {
                                    byte[] encodedBytes = new 
byte[readBufferPosition];
                                    System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0,
                                            encodedBytes, 0,
                                            encodedBytes.length);
                                    final String data = new String(
                                            encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                                    readBufferPosition = 0;

                                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                        public void run() {
                                            showToast(data);
                                        }
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        stopWorker = true;
                    }

                }
            }
        });

        workerThread.start();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

 /*
 * This will send data to be printed by the bluetooth printer
 */
  void sendData() throws IOException {
    try {

        // the text typed by the user
        String msg = "hiii";
        msg += "\n";


         mmOutputStream.write(msg.getBytes());

        // tell the user data were sent
        showToast("Data Sent");


    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  // Close the connection to bluetooth printer.
  void closeBT() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("====mmOutputStream:"+mmOutputStream);
    if(mmOutputStream!=null && mmInputStream!=null && mmSocket!=null){
    try {

        System.out.println("===-----=mmOutputStream:"+mmOutputStream);
        stopWorker = true;
        mmOutputStream.close();
        mmInputStream.close();
        mmSocket.close();
        showToast("Bluetooth Closed");
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
 }
 @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (internet.HaveNetworkConnection() ) {
    try {
        if(statusBT ){
            if (mService != null) 
                mService.stop();
        }else{
        closeBT();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    }


    public String uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {
    System.out.println("lol");
    CheckInternetConnection internet = new CheckInternetConnection(
            Activity_Sales_Return.this);
    if (!internet.HaveNetworkConnection()) {
        return "No Internet";
    }

    String serverResponse = "";
    final String fileName = sourceFileUri;
    InputStream is = null;
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024, serverResponseCode;
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);
    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        Log.e("uploadFile",
                "Source File not exist :"
                        + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                        + Utility.SALE_FILE_NAME);
        return "";
    } else {
        try {

            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
                    sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(Utility.BASE_URL
                    + "?q=webservice/send_order&token=" + api_token);
            System.out.println("======url: "+url);

            // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("xml", fileName);

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"xml\"; filename='"
                    + fileName + "'" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // create a buffer of maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            System.out.println("=======ff:" + toPrettyString(fileName, 4));
            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();
            System.out.println("----------" + serverResponseMessage);
            if (serverResponseCode == 200) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        showToast("Order Completed."); // Activity Reloading  
                                                       // here

                            try {

                                sendData();

                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }


                    }
                });
            }

            is = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            int ch;
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            while ((ch = is.read()) != -1) {
                sb.append((char) ch);
            }
            serverResponse = sb.toString();
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
            is.close();
            dialog.dismiss();
            return serverResponse;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
        return "";
    }
}



next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                      new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
            final String serverResponse = uploadFile(Environment
  .getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/"+ Utility.SALE_FILE_NAME);
}}}}}
```

Comment: Where are you exactly reloading activity? what do you mean by that?

Comment: Seems like your connection lives with the activity. You should create a new activity, service or a fragment to maintain a connection.